# Regular expressions in couchdb's views version 1.4

Tags: javascript, regex, couchdb

I have a view with regular expression.

```
var reg = /^(.*)\s\(([0-9]+)\)$/;
var res = reg.exec(baseName);
```

but after installing a new server I'm getting an error like this:

```
Log :: function raised exception (new TypeError("reg.exec is not a function", "undefined", 6)) with doc._id
```

Any ideas how to make regexps working with 1.4 couchdb on Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

Couchdb doesn't seem to support regex, when you use regex in this format:

```
var reg = /^(.*)\s\(([0-9]+)\)$/;
```

To make it work, you can initialize a RegExp object and that'll work

So change it to

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^(.*)\s\(([0-9]+)\)$/);
var res = reg.exec(baseName);
```